# Microphone picking up system sound on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, microphone

Hello I just got Ubuntu dual booted with windows 8.1 and it is working well apart from the microphone picks up any system sounds such as Youtube videos. I am using headphones so I know that the microphone isn't picking up the sound from the speakers. It doesn't pick up the sounds if I mute the volume. This doesn't happen on Windows so I doubt it's a hardware issue. Does anyone know how to fix this? The laptop is a Lenovo flex 15

Comment: Is it definitely in the correct port?

Comment: How do I check? Sorry I'm new to linux

Comment: No, I mean the hardware port, is it in the pink output? Just checking :)

Comment: Oh, my bad, It's an internal mic and it does pick up my voice it just gets system sound aswell

Comment: Ahh OK thanks... Let me check somethings... What sound / recording programs are installed?

Comment: Skype and audacity

Comment: This could be a problem with audacity, you can get it to loop back I don't know the exact place though I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1):

Run `alsamixer` in terminal.

Then go across to "loopback " switch with right arrow, and disable it with "down" arrow.

Comment: There is no loopback option, I selected the correct sound card and went to all

Comment: Can you post your alsa-info like this: Run the following  command in a terminal:
     "wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh"      
Choose the upload option and provide a link for the output.

Comment: Put alsamixer in terminal

Comment: Heres the alsa-info [link](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6d87fd4a6d099ae11979d18334683e7027dc8c57)

Comment: @laugeo http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer See the Provide context for links section. We are aiming here at SO and AU to have an independant Q/A site, without lots of links to other sites. It's fine to have the link, but you should have written the main point in the answer, so people aren't browsing all over the place.

Comment: You are right, no loopback ... I would try to disable or mute  every switch on the second card  in case of incorrect mapping between card and alsa (automute, mic level etc)